# iBeacon not found if it is already in range

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I found this good tutorial for develop an app with iBeacon:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/

But with this implementation, as the author say, if you start the receiver when it's already in the beacon range, it's not going to fire. If you want find an ibeacon you need to walk far away from its region, and then walk back into range.

How can I modify this code to find a beacon that it is in range when I lunch the app?

I use Xcode6, IPad air, IOS 8

This is the simplified code from the tutorial:

in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *myBeaconRegion;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"ACFD065E-C3C0-11E3-9BBE-1A514932AC01"];

self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                               identifier:@"com.appcoda.testregion"];

[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}




- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
 {
    NSLog(@"Finding beacons.");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}




-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"None found.");
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}




-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
   didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
          inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
NSLog(@"Beacon found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The didEnterRegion and didExitRegion callbacks only fire when the user crosses the region boundary. In the case of an iBeacon this means moving from "Inside" to "Outside" or vice versa.

When you fire up the app and start monitoring for your beacon region, you can request the current state for your beacon region to determine if your user is inside or outside.

Implement the didDetermineState callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

This callback gets triggered after you start monitoring your region, anytime a region boundary is crossed (so be careful you don't duplicate logic here and inside didEnter/ExitRegion), and in response to a call to requestStateForRegion:

Hope this helps... if you need more -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion: